# Probability of two random papers being submitted in alphabetical order

Tags: probability

I thought up this scenario and was curious if anyone could see the computation for the probability of this particular event.

> A class has $k$ students and each student turns in his/her homework on a table at the beginning of class in random order.
>
> What is the probability that in the stack of $k$ papers, exactly two appear in alphabetical order?

Comment: There are $k!$ such arrangements with $(k-2)!$ of those having two in alphabetical order. So, $(k-2)!/k!$, but this seems too straightforward.

Comment: If the letters are, say,  $ABCDEF$, is $CFEDAB$ considered as $AB$ being in alphabetical order ?

Comment: Yes, the two are allowed to occur in order at location in the stack.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question. Do $ZAYB$ and $ZAYC$ satisfy the criterion ?

Comment: Those would not. I am requiring that it must be $ZALQN\cdots ORTSB\cdots EF\cdots$ so the $EF$ is the "success"

Comment: Then my interpretation was right. Try to finish it, if you can't, I'll do it  a bit later. Watching the Australian Open.

Comment: Suggested edit: "exactly two _adjacent papers_ appear"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we shall count no two consecutive letters being sequential.

Assuming an unrestricted number of $A,B,C,...$ and that $A$ is not allowed to follow $Z$,

Let's say the first letter is $P$, then 25 choices for second $(R)$, say, 25 ways for the next and so on.

Thus P(**no** two are sequential) $= \dfrac{26\cdot25^{k-1}}{26^k} = \left(\dfrac{25}{26}\right)^{k-1}$

Can you try and modify it to P(exactly $2$ are sequential) ? Start with the first two being sequential, and develop it...

**PS**

Suppose the first two have sequential alphabets. This can happen in $26\cdot1$ way (with $A$ after $Z$ also treated as sequential). The next letter now has $25$ choices, as have each of subsequent letters, so $26\cdot1\cdot25^{k-2}$ ways.

The pair that is sequential could occur starting at any of $(k-1)$ points,
thus $Pr = \dfrac{(k-1)26\cdot25^{k-2}}{26^k}$

Comment: I would have thought with $3$ papers, the probability no pair are sequential is $\frac{3}{6}$.  I do not see how to get that from your expression.

Comment: I seem to have misinterpreted the question as no consecutive letters being sequential, have asked OP for a clarification. The wording was actually "in alphabetical order"